# Bash Scripting -> While Loop, For Loop, If Statement (Convert from MATLAB)

Tags: bash, matlab, shell

I have the following in MATLAB:

```
    while ~feof(fi)
        dline== fgetl(fi)
        if count == 0
            if dline == -1
                <do stuff>
            end
        end
        if dline(end-27) == ':'
            dline = dline(1:end-28)
        end
        <output>
        for i = 32:size(dline,2)
            if dline(i) == '{'
                count = count + 1
                sp = []
                for j = 1:count
                    sp = [sp;s]
                end
                <output>
            elseif dline(i) == '}'
                count = count - 1
                sp = []
                for j = 1:count
                    sp = [sp;s]
                end
                <output>
            elseif dline(i) == ','
                <output>
            else
                <output>
        end
    end
```

I'm having trouble with the indexing of my dline. For example in MATLAB:

```
    if dline(i) == '{'
```

Translated to shell script, I have:

```
    if [ ${line[i]} == '{' ]
```

or some variation thereof. But I'm getting errors associated with that, or it is not finding '{'. I have tried replacing 'i' with '$x', where 'x' counts up from 32 inside the loop. I have tried replacing '{' with "$match1", where '$match1' = '{'.

Please ignore any problems with the MATLAB code, I know that works and I just typed it up quickly. I'm more interested in converting that code to usable BASH Script (on Linux).

Comment: So, what exactly is your actual question...?

Comment: put double quotes around the variable which value you want to test, and remove one of the `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be working perfectly fine on Mac OS X:

```
if [ ${line[i]} == '{' ];
> then
> echo "tes"
> fi
tes
```

Comment: I have: `for i in 32:${#line}` and `if [ "${line[i]} == '{' ];`, but that does not seem to be working. I get an error on "i" (syntax error expression), and if I use "$x" in place of the "i" on my if statement, I do not go into the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding of the posted code and of what you are doing is correct, you are on the wrong track.

In the construct of `${foo[$x]}`, `foo` is an array and you are indexing an element at the position `${x}`, but you cannot treat a string in shell script as an array and index a character in that string at a particular position like this.

To achieve that you would use the `${line:start:length}` syntax to fetch a substring of `${line}` (the index is 0-based), e.g.:

```
$ foo="abc"
$ echo "${foo:0:1}"
a
$ echo "${foo:1:2}"
bc
```

Can you comment your existing code or add some pseudocode that describes your snippet so people without matlab knowledge know what it is that you are exactly trying to do? Then we can help you convert the whole thing as cleanly as possible.